# Fullscreen Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

How do I make an activity full screen? Without the notification bar.

Answer (score 1206, accepted):

You can do it programatically:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it via your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

**Edit:**

If you are using AppCompatActivity then you need to add new theme

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and then use it.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"/>
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/1646479

Comment: just android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" attribute on your activity on the manifest is enough. Thanks :)

Comment: If your app uses any other theme use corresponding theme name E.g. For White theme  `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: Set the theme in manifest causes a black screen on launch, it is better to do it in code.

Comment: if you are using ActionBar and just want no TitleBar remove the line `requestWindowFeature()' as this will cause a NullPointer otherwise

Comment: Works like wonder! Thanks. Cristian , please do you think you could help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse

Comment: On Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher, using [setSystemUiVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)) to set UI flags gives you more granular control over the system bars than using WindowManager flags.

Comment: It`s better to add the Window method`s before super.onCreate

Comment: If you are using `AppCompatActivity`, you need to put `requestWindowFeature` before `super.onCreate`. Otherwise, you will get: `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

Comment: This is a 6 years old answer and yet, it was the right one. The xml didn't work, since there is no Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen available to me, but the code worked both on KitKat and up-to-date Marshmallow.

Comment: Achieving this from the xml style doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: How come this worked, while using answer from Google docs for Android 4.1+ did not work? (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Comment: I created a separate style in styles.xml `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>`

Comment: Programmatic way not working on Nexus 5x (Android 6), only the title is removed.

Comment: This solution doesn't hide the navigation bar.

Comment: error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity` when trying to use the theme

Comment: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"  is the solution for me because if I put @android tag it gives me error

Answer (score 133):

There's a technique called [Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) available in **KitKat**.
[image: Immersive Full-Screen Mode Demo]

[Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ImmersiveMode/)

Comment: Just keep in mind that a "reminder bubble" will be displayed the first time your app enters immersive mode. This is fine for some activities, but not if you're doing a splash screen, for example.

Comment: breaks when using spinners

Comment: I actually found the other related doc a bit more useful, and also handles newer API versions more thoroughly: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge#java

Answer (score 80):

If you don't want to use the theme `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` because you are already using a theme of you own, you can use `android:windowFullscreen`.

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
  android:name=".ui.activity.MyActivity"
  android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
</activity>
```

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme"  parent="your parent theme">
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: add parent as your parent theme

Comment: you need to place 
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> too

Answer (score 55):

In **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Launch"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" > <!-- This line is important -->

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Or in **Java** code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: you must add a code to do that thing programmatically in JAVA

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score 44):

### For AndroidX

#### 1. Transparent Statusbar

```kotlin
    window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

[image]

#### 2. Transparent Statusbar & Bottomnav bar

```kotlin
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
    );
```

[image]

#### 3. Hide Statusbar

Recommended Compat solution for API 30+ (inclusive backwards compatibility)

```kotlin
  val windowInsetsController =
      WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView) ?: return
  windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
      WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
  windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

[image]

#### 4. Hide Statubar & Bottomnav bar

[API level 30:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setSystemUiVisibility(int))

> SystemUiVisibility flags are deprecated. Use WindowInsetsController instead.

Same as 3., just use `WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()`

```kotlin
    val actionBar: ActionBar? = supportActionBar
        if (actionBar != null) actionBar.hide()

    val windowInsetsController =
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView) ?: return
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

[image]

**Where to put this code ?**

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        /*  Put above code here ..... */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider)
   }
```

**Note**

- I checked this code in Pixel 3A emulator
- Maybe customise android OS not support
- set style `<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`

Comment: Thank you it worked well on some android versions but its not working on android 11:

 window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    }

Comment: window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT

in this case, systemUiVisibility/SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE/SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN component are depricated

Answer (score 37):

If your using AppCompat and ActionBarActivity, then use this

`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: This won't remove status bar on top

Comment: Why people keep upvoting this like it is related to the answer?

Answer (score 23):

Be careful with

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

If you are using any method to set the action bar as the follow:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

It will cause a null pointer exception.

Comment: Reason is because you're adjusting the action bar, which the resize code is trying to hide!

Comment: This just did nothing

Answer (score 23):

Try this with appcompat from `style.xml`. It provides support for all platforms.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>


<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: nice and easy solution. For newbies, add this theme in Activity or Application tag in AndroidManifest.xml: android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen"

Answer (score 13):

Using Android Studio (current version is 2.2.2 at moment) is very easy to add a fullscreen activity.

See the steps:

1. Right click on your java main package > Select “New” > Select “Activity” > Then, click on “Fullscreen Activity”.

[image: Step one]

2. Customize the activity (“Activity Name”, “Layout Name” and so on) and click “finish”.

[image: Step two]

**Done!**

Now you have a fullscreen activity made easily (see the java class and the activity layout to know how the things works)!

Answer (score 11):

First you must to set you app theme with "NoActionBar" like below

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Then add these lines in your fullscreen activity.

```
public class MainActiviy extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

It will hide actionbar/toolbar and also statusbar in your fullscreen activity

Answer (score 11):

For those using AppCompact...
style.xml

```
 <style name="Xlogo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Then put the name in your manifest...

Answer (score 7):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity ...
          android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme"
    >
</activity>
```

### I. Your main app the theme is *Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*

**For hide ActionBar / StatusBar**
*style.xml*

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
</style>

<style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <!--this property will help hide the ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--currently, I don't know why we need this property since use windowNoTitle only already help hide actionbar. I use it because it is used inside Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (you can check Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar code). I think there are some missing case that I don't know-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!--this property is used for hiding StatusBar-->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

**To hide the system navigation bar**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ...
    }
 }
```

### II. Your main app theme is *Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar*

**For hide ActionBar / StatusBar**
*style.xml*

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>

<style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <!--don't need any config for hide ActionBar because our apptheme is NoActionBar-->
    <!--this property is use for hide StatusBar-->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> // 
</style>
```

**To hide the system navigation bar**

**Similar** like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

[Demo](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidFullscreenActivity)

Comment: Thanks. Tested on Android 5.0.1.

Comment: @CoolMind meet you again. Thank you for your edittion

Answer (score 6):

thanks for answer @Cristian i was getting error

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called
>   before adding content

i solved this using

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    -----
    -----
}
```

Comment: Should we set `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`?

Answer (score 6):

Add this in styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Example -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And change AndroidManifest file with bellow code

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Example -

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Answer (score 5):

**Theme**

```
    <style name="Theme.FluidWallpaper.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">shortEdges</item>
     </style>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
   <activity android:exported="false"
        android:name=".FullScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FluidWallpaper.FullScreen"/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! After trying all the answers above with no effect, windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode works at last.

Comment: i have tried everything but finally this works!.```<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" >shortEdges</item>```

Comment: Tried everything all over the internet but this one, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

show Full Immersive:

```
private void askForFullScreen()
    {
        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
```

move out of full immersive mode:

```
 private void moveOutOfFullScreen() {
        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example code. You can turn on/off flags to hide/show specific parts.

[image]

```
public static void hideSystemUI(Activity activity) {
    View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    //| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    //| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

Then, you reset to the **default** state:

[image]

```
public static void showSystemUI(Activity activity) {
    View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

You can call the above functions from your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.course_activity);
    UiUtils.hideSystemUI(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use my own theme instead of using @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen. But it wasn't working as some post on here had mentioned, so I did some tweaking to figure it out.

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.MyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
</activity>
```

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Note: in my case I had to use `name="windowActionBar"` instead of `name="android:windowActionBar"` before it worked properly. So I just used both to make sure in the case I need to port to a new Android version later.

Answer (score 3):

**KOTLIN**

Following the google doc, there is a easy way :

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI() }


private fun hideSystemUI() {
// Enables regular immersive mode.
// For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
// Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)      }


// Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private fun showSystemUI() {
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = 
(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)       }
```

[Google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

To make your activity full screen do this:

```
    // add following lines before setContentView
    // to hide toolbar
                if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //to hide status bar
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This will hide the toolbar and status bar.

But In some case, you may want to show status bar with a transparent background, in that case, do this:

```
// add following lines before setContentView
// to hide toolbar
if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
   getSupportActionBar().hide();
// to make status bar transparent
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Some other alternate to hide toolbar instead of 
`getSupportActionBar().hide()`:

1. Remove toolbar by changing the app theme's parent:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

2. If you want to remove the toolbar from only one activity then go to manifest, under activity tag add this: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

**For kotlin lovers**, why not use extension functions:

For first case:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.makeItFullScreenStatusBarVisible(){
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
}
```

And call this before `setContentView`:

```
makeItFullScreenStatusBarVisible()
```

For Second One:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.makeItFullScreenStatusBarHidden(){
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

And call it before `setContentView`:

```
makeItFullScreenStatusBarHidden()
```

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.decorView.windowInsetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") // Older API support
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

just call this fun :

```
private fun changeScreenSystemUiController(isFullScreen: Boolean) {
    window?.also {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it, !isFullScreen)
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(it, it.decorView).apply {
            systemBarsBehavior =
                if (isFullScreen)
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                else
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_TOUCH
            if (isFullScreen)
                hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            else
                show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            it.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
                if (isFullScreen)
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
                else
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_DEFAULT
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TIP: Using getWindow().setLayout() can screw up your full screen display!  Note the documentation for this method says:

> Set the width and height layout parameters of the window...
>   you can change them to ... an absolute value to make a window that is not full-screen.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setLayout%28int,%20int%29

For my purposes, I found that I had to use setLayout with absolute parameters to resize my full screen window correctly.  Most of the time, this worked fine.  It was called by an onConfigurationChanged() event.  There was a hiccup, however.  If the user exited the app, changed the orientation, and reentered, it would lead to firing off my code which included setLayout().  During this re-entry time window, my status bar (which was hidden by the manifest) would be made to re-appear, but at any other time setLayout() would not cause this!  The solution was to add an additional setLayout() call after the one with the hard values like so:

```
       public static void setSize( final int width, final int height ){
//DO SOME OTHER STUFF...
            instance_.getWindow().setLayout( width, height );
            // Prevent status bar re-appearance
            Handler delay = new Handler();
            delay.postDelayed( new Runnable(){ public void run() {
                instance_.getWindow().setLayout(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );
            }}, FILL_PARENT_ON_RESIZE_DELAY_MILLIS );
        }
```

The window then correctly re-sized, and the status bar did not re-appear regardless of the event which triggered this.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

Comment: In the else it would be better to use the following:
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: Thanks! It worked with fragments and the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Activity :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifests:

```
 <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
            ></activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    adjustFullScreen(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        adjustFullScreen(getResources().getConfiguration());
    }
}
private void adjustFullScreen(Configuration config) {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    } else {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside *styles.xml*...

```
<!-- No action bar -->
<style name="NoActonBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Theme customization. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#444</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#999</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

With kotlin this is the way I did:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

    }
}
```

**Immersive Mode**

The immersive mode is intended for apps in which the user will be heavily interacting with the screen. Examples are games, viewing images in a gallery, or reading paginated content, like a book or slides in a presentation. For this, just add this lines:

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

**Sticky immersive**

In the regular immersive mode, any time a user swipes from an edge, the system takes care of revealing the system bars—your app won't even be aware that the gesture occurred. So if the user might actually need to swipe from the edge of the screen as part of the primary app experience—such as when playing a game that requires lots of swiping or using a drawing app—you should instead enable the "sticky" immersive mode.

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

For more information: [Enable fullscreen mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive?authuser=3)

In case your using the keyboard, sometimes happens that StatusBar shows when keyboard shows up. In that case I usually add this to my style xml

styles.xml

```
<style name="FullScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

And also this line to my manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
```

Comment: Thanks. Requires API 16 and 19.

Answer (score 2):

Just paste this code into `onCreate()` method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this method after setContentView in onCreate() and pass the **Window** object by **getWindow()**.

```
    public void makeActivityFullScreen(Window window){
    View decorView = window.getDecorView();
    //        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
       window.getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    );
}
```

This code will work for notch screen also. To check the notch fullscreen you require android P but if You have a notch display phone then go to **setting-->Display setting -->app display ratio --->select your app** --->there will be two options safe are display and full screen , please select the full screen and run the app, you can see the fullscreen in notch also **without having android Pie**

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS); if (getSupportActionBar() != null){ getSupportActionBar().hide(); }`

Comment: The code in this answer was given in many others, what it brings new?

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that system navigation bar was not hiding after calling. Also in my case I needed landscape, so just in case comment that line and that all.
First of all create style

```
    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

This is my manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
    </activity>
```

This is my spalsh activity

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
/** Duration of wait **/
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_creen);

    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Splash.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
}
```

And this is my main full screen activity. onSystemUiVisibilityChange thi method is quit important otherwise android main navigation bar after calling will stay and not disappear anymore. Really irritating problem, but this function solves that problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private View mContentView;
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    
    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen2);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null)
    {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_text);
    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);



    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
            (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                {
                    System.out.println("print");

                    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                    {
                        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

                        }
                }
            });

}

}
```

This is my splash screen layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/splashscreen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World, splash"/>
</LinearLayout>

This is my fullscreen layout
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0099cc"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:text="@string/dummy_content2"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty activity and add two lines in `onCreate`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // full screen activity
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display content through the notch or the cutout area. This can help from the docs:

> LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES - Content renders into the cutout area in both portrait and landscape modes.

Key thing for me was this line in the activity style:

```
// Important to draw through the cutouts
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

For me, I wanted to show an image in immersive mode. When I click it, I want the system UI (status & navigation bars) to show up.

Here is my solution:

1- In the Activity, some methods to show/hide system UI (status/nav bars)

```
private fun hideSystemUI() {
    sysUIHidden = true
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE 
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // Hide nav bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // Hide status bar
            )
}


private fun showSystemUI() {
    sysUIHidden = false
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION // layout Behind nav bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN // layout Behind status bar
            )
}
```

2- Make sure this in the root view of your xml layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

3- Style for Full screen Activity will give status/navigation bars a semi transparent background when they show up:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#50000000</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#50000000</item>
    // Important to draw behind cutouts
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> 
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sysTransparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.Type

fun Activity.fullscreen() {
    with(WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)) {
        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        hide(Type.systemBars())
    }
}

fun Activity.exitFullscreen() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).show(Type.systemBars())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of these answers seem to be outdated. developer.android.com recommends to do it like this:

Kotlin:

```
private fun hideSystemBars() {
    val windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```

Java:

```
private void hideSystemBars() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
    if (windowInsetsController == null) {
        return;
    }
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
}
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

Answer (score 1):

According to Android developer [training](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#kotlin)

You should do the following:

Kotlin:

```kotlin
private fun hideSystemBars() {
  val windowInsetsController =
      ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
  // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
  windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
      WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
  // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
  windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```

Java:

```java
private void hideSystemBars() {
  WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
      ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
  if (windowInsetsController == null) {
    return;
  }
  // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
  windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
      WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
  );
  // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
  windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android 10, none worked for me.

But I that worked perfectly fine (1st line in oncreate):

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    setContentView(....);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution from mozilla, they made an extension library [here](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/blob/main/components/support/ktx/src/main/java/mozilla/components/support/ktx/android/view/Activity.kt)

In case link breakes here is the code

```
/**
 * Retrieves a {@link WindowInsetsControllerCompat} for the top-level window decor view.
 */
fun Window.getWindowInsetsController(): WindowInsetsControllerCompat {
    return WindowInsetsControllerCompat(this, this.decorView)
}


/**
 * Attempts to call immersive mode using the View to hide the status bar and navigation buttons.
 * @param onWindowFocusChangeListener optional callback to ensure immersive mode is stable
 * Note that the callback reference should be kept by the caller and be used for [exitImmersiveModeIfNeeded] call.
 */
fun Activity.enterToImmersiveMode(
    onWindowFocusChangeListener: ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener? = null
) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    window.getWindowInsetsController().apply {
        hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }

    // We need to make sure system bars do not become permanently visible after interactions with content
    // see https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/20240
    onWindowFocusChangeListener?.let {
        window.decorView.viewTreeObserver?.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(it)
    }
}

/**
 * Attempts to come out from immersive mode using the View.
 * @param onWindowFocusChangeListener optional callback to ensure immersive mode is stable
 * Note that the callback reference should be kept by the caller and be the same used for [enterToImmersiveMode] call.
 */
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun Activity.exitImmersiveModeIfNeeded(
    onWindowFocusChangeListener: ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener? = null
) {
    if (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON and window.attributes.flags == 0) {
        // We left immersive mode already.
        return
    }
    onWindowFocusChangeListener?.let {
        window.decorView.viewTreeObserver?.removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener(it)
    }
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    window.getWindowInsetsController().apply {
        show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
getWindow().addFlags(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Please describe your solution.  New users probably don't know where to put this.

Comment: you can put it in onCreate of your activity