# how to set video in full screen

Tags: java, android, video

hai how set video in full screen now i am attach my screen shot....

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="videothumb.videothumb"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".videothumb" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name="ViewVideo" android:label="@string/app_name"    
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
   <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   </application>
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS">
   </uses-permission>
   </manifest>
```

ViewVideo.java

```
package videothumb.videothumb;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class ViewVideo extends Activity {
  private String filename;
  private VideoView Video;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        Video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
        System.gc();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        filename = extras.getString("videofilename");
        Video.setVideoPath(filename);
        Video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        Video.requestFocus();
        Video.start();
    }

  } `
```

xml coding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<VideoView 
android:id="@+id/VideoView01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android

Comment: i try this coding..till same problem check my mainfest. what mistake i made......help me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in your class that contains mediaplayer code.

and in your xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: yes i tried this method. now i am post xml,java source code and manifest coding also please check my coding what mistake i made for this coding.....waiting for your reply.....

Comment: And one more thing is you use either theme in menifest file or by programmatically (requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
). you  should not use both.

Comment: sorry, you have put that lines in your class. now just remove theme from your menifest file. than do clean-build and try to run you code.

Comment: 1. i have put that lines in my class..and change frame layout...removed theme in manifest.....after run my project same screen will be display

Comment: you have use two class right? so what are you doing in your first class?

Answer (score 3):

No need of code to play video in full screen mode

#### Apply the following layout format over the xml containing the videoview it will for sure will play the video in full screen mode. as it is running mine :) Hope it helps

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

my java file:

public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {

```
VideoView mVideoView;
MediaController mc;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);//if you want.
    File video = new File("your file path");
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mc = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
    mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(video.getAbsolutePath());
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();

}
```

my xml layout:

and my Menifest file:

Comment: now i am expect landscape format. your coding working fine...but that type still i am trying...if u got tell me.....

Comment: i have check your code in my eclipse and it doesnt show title bar or status bar i have just remove system.gc(); from your code.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in your manifest, at this line `<activity android:name="ViewVideo"`,you forgot to put a dot(.) before the "ViewVideo". It should be ".ViewVideo"