# How to set XML fullscreen in Android

Tags: android, xml

How do I create a full screen mode in XML irregardless of how small what contents are in it?

Here's my "show.xml" code:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">    

<Button android:id="@+id/ok_btn" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:typeface="sans" android:text="ok"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to display it like another full screen page, with black background, like a main.xml. In this case, its like a pop-up screen. Removing or changing the android:layout_width and android:layout_heigh don't work. help please!  :(

Comment: I dont understand how do you mean that it looks like pop-up screen. Maybe you are creating it as a dialog instead of activity? You should call it like this: Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MyActivity.class); startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Afaik you can't do fullscreen in xml. You have two choices:

1. `AndroidManifest.xml` in activity's section

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

2. in `onCreate()` before calling `setContentView`

```
requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );

getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
```

Comment: This works for me. For 2nd option (when code in onCreate) add the given two lines before setContentView method call.

Answer (score 20):

As the other answer doesn't work for me:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Fullscreen">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Add this style to your styles.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".TitlesActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen">
```

Make sure your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml refers to your theme.

Comment: This is just more proper IMO

Comment: Agreed, the question was about fullscreen in XML. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ControllerApp.NoActionBar"/>
```

Add in MainActivity.java:

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, previous answers did not work for me, but this line from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-full-screen-mode-in-android/) works like a miracle:

> Made these changes in your manifest.xml file
>
> ```
> android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
> ```