# How to set screen size to full screen at runtime in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-theme

I want to change the screen layout in my application to full screen when the user click on button but it didn't work, **my code** is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnFullScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFullScreen);
    btnNormalScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNormalScreen);

    btnFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppBaseThemeFullScreen);

        }
    });

    btnNormalScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppBaseTheme);

        }
    });



}
```

And my **Full Screen theme** is:

```
<style name="AppBaseThemeFullScreen" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And my **Normal theme** is

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

So if there is any way to do that please help me.

Comment: Is there anything in the logcat?

Comment: i think you will need to use `parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` instead of `parent="android:Theme.Light"` for full screen ?

Comment: Check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843825/how-to-set-xml-fullscreen-in-android

Comment: the theme should be set before set content view to take effect

so just call setcontentview after setting the theme too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
void toggleFullScreen(boolean goFullScreen){   
    if(goFullScreen){
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }else{
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    yourView.requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the theme from the code, it seems you have to do it before calling `setContentView()`.

You can also try:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```