# YoutubePlayer - Navigation Bar Overlay

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using `YoutubePlayerSupportFragment` in my application. I am adding `YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT` flag. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT) I know my player won't rebuffer after exiting from full screen, but now I have to handle Action Bar and Navigation Bar. But the documentation doesn't say or point to how I can handle these cases.

Now the problem I am facing is so far only occurring in Asus Nexus 7 OS 5.1.1. I also have an LG G2 D802 OS 4.4.2, Samsung Galaxy TAB GT P5113 OS 4.4.2 and Samsung Galaxy Tab SM-T310 OS 4.2.2 and they do not throw Overlay Error. In the Log cat I get the following Message.

```
03-09 15:54:39.760  11203-11203/com.jadoo.jadooplus W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI﹕ 
YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. 
The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.view.View{c067400 V.ED.... ........ 0,736-1280,800 #1020030 android:id/navigationBarBackground}.
Top edge 24 px above YouTubePlayerView's bottom edge. .
```

So I know the problem *is* in the Navigation Bar. Navigation Bar is overlaying on  top of the Player.

My Questions are these

- Why am I not getting the same Error on other devices?
- How Can I handle System Navigation Bar, so that when I am in fullscreen I can still get Navigation Bar if/when I want to stop the player (on back press) without overlaying it on the player.

I tried Listening for Click Events But in Full Screen Mode I can't get any so I tried `Overriding` `dispatchTouchEvent()` in the Activity and get a Click event my self but even that doesn't help me get rid of Navigation Bar in Time (before time actually).

I also tried listening for System UI change via `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` and hiding navigation bar there (but again perhaps too early to hide navigation bar).

I have set `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` in android manifest file so I don't really need to hide the action/status bar just the navigation bar.

Also if anyone can confirm it is device specific issue, it'll be a great help.

Comment: I used YouTube and noticed that if he little space on the screen, the player sees strange. For example, I did not work opening event or ful screenshot video is not opened. I had to remove the toolbar from this. This does not happen at all devices

Comment: @PeDuCKA My apologies but I didn't understand your comment. Could u rephrase? Also you say this issue does not occur at all devices: could you say on which devices it does (a classification of devices or a fixed number of devices)? Also if there is a workaround to the problem please do tell.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but somehow I didn't receive notification.

Comment: see another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027758/play-list-of-youtube-videos-in-listview/36028550#36028550

Comment: @PeDuCKA I still don't get it. My problem is completely different. I am not trying to draw any of my own views on top of the YoutubePlayerSupportFragment. It is the navigation bar that is coming over. There is nothing there I can do to either solve my problem or a workaround.

Comment: Also I am not making YoutubePlayer any smaller than 200x110 px.

Comment: I got a similar error for nokia player although reproduced in full screen, but it did not work due to the fact that there was toolbar. I had to remove it and it worked

Comment: @PeDuCKA So what you are saying is I should remove navigationbar entirely from my application?
Unfortunately Navigation Bar is an integral part of my Application's UI. I also need the navigation bar to close the player on backpress.
Also what I don't get is it works fine When I am not using the above mentioned flag (Youtube Dev Team probably handles it somehow). And this is what I want to do. Or atleast a workaround.

Comment: I removed only where used youtube player

Comment: and you can try to remove if it will work, you will find the cause of the problem

Comment: @PeDuCKA Sure while the navigation bar is hidden playback works as well as anything.
`public static void hideNavigationBar(Activity activity)
 {
  if(activity != null)
  { View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();

   int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
   decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
  }
 }`
This is what I do to hide the navigation bar, and then use SystemUIVisibilityChangeListener to know when it has comes back on. But in the Listener changing Navigation bar's visibility doesn't work.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633313/how-to-set-screen-size-to-full-screen-at-runtime-in-android

Comment: @augtonov I checked the link but it is a completely different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how went around the problem (this is still not a solution but its the closest I can get to).

So, I added an `OnSystemUiChangeListener` in the `onInitializationSuccess` of `YoutubePlayerSupportFragment` (or `YoutubePlayerFragment`).

```
(View) getView().getParent().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener();
```

provide an implemented object of `OnSystemUiChangeListener`.

Override the method `onSystemUiVisibilityChange()` like so:

```
@Override
public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

    if (visibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE) {
        scheduleNavigationBarHide();
    }
    else if (visibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION || visibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            || visibility == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) {
        if (navigationBarHandler != null) {
            navigationBarHandler.cancel();
            navigationBarHandler.purge();
            navigationBarHandler = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Provide definition for the method scheduleNavigationBarHide().

```
private void scheduleNavigationBarHide() {


    if (navigationBarHandler != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Canceling navigationBarHandler.");
        navigationBarHandler.cancel();
        navigationBarHandler.purge();
        navigationBarHandler = null;
    }

    if (mContext != null && mContext instanceof JadooTVActivity) {
        navigationBarHandler = new Timer();

        navigationBarHandler.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                ((JadooTVActivity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!isPlayerSqueezed) {
                            hideAsImmersiveNavigationBar(Config.context);
                        }
                        else {
                            Utils.showNavigationBar(Config.context);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

So finally `hideAsImmersiveNavigationBar()` as you might have guessed this works by making the `Navigation Bar` temporarily immersive. Here's how

```
private void hideAsImmersiveNavigationBar(Activity activity) {

    if(activity != null)
    {   View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();

        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

Later when player has closed you might wanna bring back the `Navigation Bar`. Change the UI Flags to `int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE   | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;`

**Finally a little disclaimer:** I have provided a list of devices the application has been tested, I don't know if this will work on every devices. If you do find a device where the issue is persistent then feel free to comment. Also Immersive mode was added from API 19 so the solution will not work on any device before that, but I only had the issue on one device running API 21. All the older devices worked well. Also If/when the `Navigation Bar` stays for 1 second, we still get the overlay error.

Answer (score 0):

change activity to full screen when youtube is fullscreen.

```
 void toggleFullScreen(boolean goFullScreen){   
    if(goFullScreen){
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }else{ 
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } 

    yourView.requestLayout(); 
}
```

Comment: I will try the solution, and let u know if it works better than mine. Thanks!