# Play list of youtube videos in listview

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am facing problem with show and play list of youtube videos. Let me explain, I have a fragment and placed on listview. In that list have separate child view for each item. I was placed  `<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView>` tag and also try to place Fragment. In both cases I am getting Binary Inflated exception. Please tell me any solution for my problem.

```
Process: com.example.sampleexamplefor_recyclerview, PID: 6510
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.example.sampleexamplefor_recyclerview.RecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.java:40)
            at com.example.sampleexamplefor_recyclerview.RecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.java:24)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5288)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4551)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2186)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1920)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1106)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6018)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.example.sampleexamplefor_recyclerview.RecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.java:40)
            at com.example.sampleexamplefor_recyclerview.RecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.java:24)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5288)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4551)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15684)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2186)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1920)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1106)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6018)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by:
```

Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.VideoInfoHolder> implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

    //these ids are the unique id for each video
    String[] VideoID = {"P3mAtvs5Elc", "nCgQDjiotG0", "P3mAtvs5Elc"};
    Context ctx;
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;
    private MyPlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener;
    private YouTubePlayer player;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public VideoInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder. youTubeView.initialize("AIzaSyCS8nKb2V9RROPP3ehy4mhQbwhVdfe7V8o", this);
        playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
        playbackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();

        holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                player.play();

            }
        });

        final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener  onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };

        holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        /*holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize("AIzaSyCS8nKb2V9RROPP3ehy4mhQbwhVdfe7V8o", new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
                youTubeThumbnailLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader;
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoID[position]);
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                //write something for failure
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return VideoID.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean b) {
        this.player = player;
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        if (!b) {
            player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }

    public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
        YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
        protected ImageView playButton;
        private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

        public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            playButton=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
            youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
//            youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)itemView. findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, "AIzaSyCS8nKb2V9RROPP3ehy4mhQbwhVdfe7V8o", VideoID[getLayoutPosition()]);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }


    private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
            // Called when playback starts, either due to user action or call to play().

        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            // Called when playback is paused, either due to user action or call to pause().
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            // Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused.
        }

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
            // Called when buffering starts or ends.
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int i) {
            // Called when a jump in playback position occurs, either
            // due to user scrubbing or call to seekRelativeMillis() or seekToMillis()
        }
    }

    private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            // Called when the player is loading a video
            // At this point, it's not ready to accept commands affecting playback such as play() or pause()
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {
            // Called when a video is done loading.
            // Playback methods such as play(), pause() or seekToMillis(int) may be called after this callback.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
            // Called when playback of an advertisement starts.
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            // Called when playback of the video starts.
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            // Called when the video reaches its end.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            // Called when an error occurs.
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"

        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"

        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"/>
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="#707070"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/btnYoutube_player"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="center"

                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the stack trace. It says caused by at the end.

Comment: It looks as though you are using a `RecyclerView`, not a `ListView`. Could you include the full stack trace in your post, along with the code for your `Adapter` class and layout file for the row inflated in `onCreateViewHolder()` please?

Answer (score 2):

of [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment#Overview),

> Note that while videos are playing, this View has a minimum size of 200x110 dp. If you make the view any smaller, videos will automatically stop playing. Also, it is not permitted to overlay this fragment's view with other views while a video is playing.

Answer (score 1):

**xml code: list_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnYoutube_player"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/videosTitle_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Vidoes title here"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
package com.mobileappdev.videosapp.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView;
import com.mobileappdev.videosapp.R;

/**
 * Created by ofaroque on 8/13/15.
 */
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.VideoInfoHolder> {

    //these ids are the unique id for each video
    String[] VideoID = {"P3mAtvs5Elc", "nCgQDjiotG0", "P3mAtvs5Elc"};
    String[] Ttitles = {"Video # 1", "Video # 2", "Video # 3"};
    Context ctx;
    private static String KEY = "Add your authentication key for google";

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public VideoInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder, final int position) {


        final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };

        holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoID[position]);

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
                holder.videosTitleTextView.setText(Ttitles[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                //write something for failure
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return VideoID.length;
    }

    public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
        YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
        protected ImageView playButton;
        protected TextView videosTitleTextView;

        public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            playButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
            videosTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videosTitle_tv);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
            youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, KEY, VideoID[getLayoutPosition()]);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
 package com.mobileappdev.videosapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.mobileappdev.videosapp.adapter.RecyclerAdapter;
    import com.mobileappdev.videosapp.models.Videos;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            //to use RecycleView, you need a layout manager. default is LinearLayoutManager
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
```

Comment: but performance wise small problem is there.overall appreciable nice code.