# Play YouTube Video Url into listview

Tags: android

I am new in android development.

I want to play YouTube video url into listview. I have generated API key already.
I can play YouTube on simple View but can not play into listview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027758/play-list-of-youtube-videos-in-listview/36028550#36028550

Comment: just check your fragment size in listview?