# Youtube API - Touch Event Passed to Views Behind Youtube Player

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, android-touch-event

I am using a `YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI` in my Android App.

In my `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` I am setting `youtubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);` so that I can change between Fullscreen without having to rebuffer each time I do so.

For that I removed the navigation bar please see my previous [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909260/youtubeplayer-navigation-bar-overlay) question about it. So now the player is playing fine. But somehow the touch events are passing down behind the player (i.e. to views behind youtube player) but *Only* when touch events are below the player's SeekBar (In FullScreen Mode).

Is there any workarounds to this problem?

Any one knows of any open issues regarding this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `android:clickable="true"` to the top ViewGroup of your fragment's layout file.

Comment: I believe a similar solution will work. Override container and consume all touch events.
But I will get back to you on this, currently I cannot test my theory.
Thanks!