# android fullscreen for first activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make the first Activity Fullscreen, if the user click on The Next Button it display next activity with the title and status bar

```
<activity
        android:name=".firstACT"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >...</activity>
```

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: and this is not working for you?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android

Comment: @Jeff Bic have u check my answer

Comment: I want only the first actvity be fullscreen

Answer (score -1):

do like this ,

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainSplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
    </activity>
```