# How to Set Application to full screen and Landscape Mode only?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FullScreen Activity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

I'm developing an Android Game and I need to know how to set the application to full screen and how to set the app to Landscape mode only. How should I do this?

Comment: @@user1956475  I have posted solution of your problem please check it. It might help you.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest set the following theme to your activity to make it fullscreen.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

And set this to make it fixed to landscape orientation

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your xml for the activity place the following:

```
 android:screenOrientation="lands cape"

 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Manifest way - For whole Application**

you should specify this feature in your `Manifest.xml` - `<application>`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

---

**2. Inside your code - For specific Activity**

in your `onCreate` method work both these approaches:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: The code to be entered into the Manifest had to be placed into each individual activity tag, because I already had an artribute for android:theme but it works great thanks!

Comment: @user1956475 : then try the 2nd way - `For Specific Activity` inside all of your activity.

Comment: How do I remove the Title Bar At the Top?

Comment: @user1956475 : use `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in all your activity to make it w/o title bar

Comment: I did put that and the application crashed!

Comment: @user1956475 wat log stack trace says??

Comment: @user1956475: using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` and `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` both at same time may causes error due to conflicts. So Please try to use either one of them

Comment: I got Activity Destroy TimeOut in AIDE Logcat

Comment: I didn't let them go at the same time

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line in `AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<activity android:name=".FullScreen" android:label="@string/app_title_home"  android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

**Edit your activity class like this.**

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```