# Set full screen to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fullscreen

I can set the full screen to activity easily but i want to set it for api below 10. how to do it.

```
          @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android

Comment: i want to set full screen activity lower than api 10?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN "Added in API level 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can set the full screen to activity easily but i want to set it for api below 10

That works down to API 1. I don't know why you are assuming it won't work on anything below API 10.

Edit:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10){ // set your flags  }
```

Comment: you did not understand my question, i want to set for api 1-10 and after 11 no full screen????

Comment: If you want to know the API version use `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.