# Android holoeverywhere fullscreen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-holo-everywhere, android-fullscreen, holoeverywhere

i want to know how to set my activity to fullscreen. i know how to do it normally without using the holoeverywhere libs. but i cant get it to work using holoeverywhere.

This is what i have inside my on create method trying to do this

```
public class MainActivity extends org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity implements AdListener,
        OnClickListener, org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Full Screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(ThemeManager.FULLSCREEN, ThemeManager.NO_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

on my Manifest i have this

```
<application
    android:name="org.holoeverywhere.app.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme" >
```

What am i missing, is there something that i am doing wrong or what?, because with these settings i still cannot get the main activity to be full screen.

## Solution

In the manifest i did this inside the application brackets in the manifest

```
android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Have you tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android

Comment: @Outofdate thats how you do it for a normal activity without holoeverywhere

Comment: @Outofdate as a matter a fact i tried something i didnt know was possible thanks to your reply i got an idea of how to fix it