# How to hide status bar in android in just one activity

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to hide status bar / notification bar in splash screen I am using
style:`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
this dose not hide the status bar, how should i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide status bar in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you want to remove status bar then use this before setContentView(layout) in onCreateView method

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

[credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544222/5962715)

Comment: use getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) if you want to add it back.

Comment: @Kharda Thanks that helped a lot

Comment: Damn, I was using it after setContentView(), haha, thanks man

Answer (score 31):

You can do something like below for appropriately setting theme on your particular activity -

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_theme</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: thanks man
very good approach if you want to avoid hiding status bar animation after the view has been drawn

Comment: The `android:windowFullscreen` is what is was looking for using in my `styles.xml` – it works wonderfully for me and the same as `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` for me!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Below Code to solve your problem.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Add Below line to hide 
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
```

Comment: this hides the `ActionBar` and if you are using style: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` your app will crash

Answer (score 2):

Try this complete solution for backward below android version 16 and forward compatible solution

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
    {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else
    {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Kotlin users.**

In `styles.xml` add new style:

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Now in `AndroidManifest.xml` add newly created style:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

 >...</activity>
```

Finally in `MainActivity.kt` make following changes:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Add below line to hide status bar
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
}
```

Now the status bar should be gone:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make your activity fullscreen, add this code in `onCreate` before `setContentView`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used and it worked perfectly.

Add this code to your activity `onCreate` before `setContentView`:

```
    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using this in theme app

> Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar

change to

> Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

and add code in activity:

```
fun fullScreen(activity: Activity) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    if (activity.window.insetsController != null) {
        val insetsController = activity.window.insetsController
        if (insetsController != null) {
            insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
            insetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
                WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    }
} else {
    activity.window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide status bar line and action bar, you have to change the line in themes.xml

```
   <style name="Theme.MyApp" 
           parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
   <style name="Theme.MyApp" 
            parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

and this to activity class in which you don't want status bar line..

```
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Plz make sure that you have to add these lines above this in onCreate() method.

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some magic code. Buttons in the status bar can be clicked, but it's difficult. Part for 4.4 does not work well.

```
    /** Скрывает статус-бар */
    private void hideStatusBar(View decorView)
    {
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null)
            actionBar.hide();
    }

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            try
            {
                // for < 4.0
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                // for > 4.0
                else
                {
                    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

                    hideStatusBar(decorView);

                    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
                    {
                        @Override public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                        {
                            if (visibility != View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
                                hideStatusBar(decorView);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Throwable t)
            {
                Util.log("Ошибка при попытке свернуть статус бар");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the status bar then

For Java

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

For Kotlin

```
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

For flutter

```
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```