# Non-deprecated way to hide status bar on android?

Tags: android

I have seen two ways to disable the status bar. Both of them are deprecated.

The first one from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status#java):

```java
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

The other one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070210/7743076), for example:

```java
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

In the first method `setSystemUiVisibility` is deprecated, and in the second method `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` is deprecated. What is a non-deprecated/current way to hide the status bar on android? I'd prefer a method which hides the status bar throughout the app, not just in one activity.

Comment: That you could do it in styles.xml

Comment: @SandrinJoy Can you please give exact instructions? Thanks.

Comment: sorry my bad , thought it was action bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.mainView)
frameLayout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

for the new android version, where R.id.mainView is your main layout.
Please check this for more details: https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-windowinsets-on-android-11-a80cf8fe19be

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else reading this, the non-deprecated method is `getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)`, but you can't use it unless your minSDK is Android R.

Comment: @HuzaifaHussain setSystemBarsAppearance what about this?