# Hide notification bar on splash screen API 31

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-12, android-api-31, android-splashscreen

Is it possible to hide the notification bar on splash screen with the new Android 12 Splash screen API? So that the notification bar would be hidden from the very moment when the user launches an app.

I tried adding this to my Theme.SplashScreen

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide status bar in android in just one activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968600/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android-in-just-one-activity)

Comment: @mefahimrahman I do not use an activity for my splash screen. We are talking about the splash screen that was introduced in API 31.

Comment: although you've used different theme this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status) may help. Thanks

Comment: @mefahimrahman thank you I tried but it does not help. I would like to know if hiding the notification bar is possible with the new SplashScreen API in Android 12, without workarounds. So the status bar would be hidden from the moment user launches an app, until the splash screen disappears.

Comment: 5 months later. I am having the very same issue. Has anybody found a solution for this? I have tried `actionBar?.hide()` both before and after `installSplashScreen()`. It doesn't work either way (and creates some real ugliness before).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. I've also tried all different methods including :

1. SplashScreen Theme

```
<style name="Theme.SplashScreen.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launch</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">5000</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.ComposeDemos</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

2. Code for hiding status bar suggested by Android

```kotlin
// onCreate
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
actionBar?.hide()

// and
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
} else {
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

nothing works. The code parts only affects the first Activity and not Splash Screen.

I think the closest you can do is to create an Splash screen activity instead of using SplashScreen API.

Answer (score -1):

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Put above code in onCreateMethod of the activity of Splash Screen.

Comment: I do not use an activity for my splash screen. We are talking about the splash screen that was introduced in API 31. Also, FLAG_FULLSCREEN is deprecated.