# How to disable bottom navigation buttons(Back,Home,recent apps/menu) in android permanently?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

i am having non rooted device. i want to disable `BottomNavigationView` `buttons`.i used below codes but none are working.

```
public void disablebottombars() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}

public void FullScreencall() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        //for higher api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you aren't just [making the app fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543268/android-making-a-fullscreen-application)?

Comment: making app full screen not helps me. i want to disable all bottom and top navigations of default system UI .

Comment: you simply cant, as it is not your permission to disable user's navigation and  top bar. If you were able, then you would be able to block the users' devices at some point. This is malware behavior.

Comment: @GajuKrishnan if you own the device, you can set up a [single-purpose device](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html). As Vlad mentioned, if your app runs on other devices, you can't do it

Comment: @VladMatvienko we have our own devices. what we do is we sell our devices with only our app installed in it. so my requirement is just disable all top and bottomnavigation views so user can not able to access system resources.

Comment: that does not matter on which devices you are going to use your app. It is not possible due to that you may want to install your app on other users' devices, and nobody can let you have such permissions just because you say that you promise to install it only to your specific devices. What you can do about this is to root or create custom rom for that specific devices, and deliver them rooted/with custom rom.

Comment: Also there is a chance that a `kiosk mode` could help you achieve what you want.

Comment: @VladMatvienko How to create custom rom?

Comment: This question does not relate to your question. If you have another question - ask another question here. Also don't forget to search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at setting up a [Single-purpose device](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html). To do this, your app needs to be set as a device owner, which can be done by invoking `adb shell dpm set-device-owner`. You can have a look at [Google's DPC sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc) for full details.