# How to make an android app/game take the whole screen of a phone while running?

Tags: android

I tried to make a simple game using android studio.When i test it out on my android 6(5.5 inches length phone),the game runs smoothly and takes the whole screen of my phone(i used canvas,color,and jgp files but i didnt use any kind of xml methods to implement the game objects).But the main problem is whenever i try to run it on a bigger screen like on a Tab,then the game doesnt take that device's whole screen,it almost uses half of it's screen and so some of the logic that i put into the code also doesnt work properly,like: clash detection doesnt work accurately.
I want to know how i can make my android studio project run smoothly on every available devices so that it takes the whole screen everytime?

Comment: Which layout have you used for your project? Also, can you share screenshot of the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26547124/7377534

Comment: I did not use any xml method to implement my game objects...but i set the layout as linear layout in the xml file

Comment: Usama Nasir sorry it didnt help