# How to set Full screen for an activty

Tags: android

When i launch my application , it shows up a title bar at the top containing application name, How to set Full Screen view of your main activity , when application is launched.

Comment: Refer the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you application's manifest file , set the following propery in `<application>` TAG.

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: want hide only bottom navigation bar not the status bar. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this programmatically as below

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

on the create activity and before setting our layout

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` to remove Actionbar and 
 `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` to remove title in `style`.

Comment: want hide only bottom navigation bar not the status bar. Is it possible to do?