# Unable to display the full screen mode in android

Tags: java, android, fullscreen

> Splash Screen Launcher Activity
>
> Unable to display full screen mode in android
>         package com.example.wabco;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
         final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 3000;
            /** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
            Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

            int wait = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
            try {
            super.run();
            /**
            * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
            * the wait variable for every 100L.
            */
            while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
            sleep(100);
            wait += 100;

            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } finally {
            /**
            * Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
            * times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
            */
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
            }
            }
            };
            welcomeThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> Login Activity
>
> Next Activity Login Page

```
package com.example.wabco;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> splash layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/spalshscreen"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.wabco.SplashScreen" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

> activity_login

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.wabco.LoginActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="178dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonlogin" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Attached Screenshot of Log/Error

[image]

> manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wabco"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Comment: @M D getting the same error following that post.

Answer (score 1):

just replace this 4 lines in splashScreen.java  in OnCreate()

```
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
```

Comment: tried it its not hiding the title and navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

add these line in oncreate

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

use this

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Tried this app force closes and getting an error IllegalStateException you need to use Theme.AppCombat (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269642/2058260
cheack this or you can simply change ActionBarActivity to activity

Comment: Hi @H4SN, I have extended ActionBarActivity changed it to activity. With that code i can hide the title bar but not the navigation bar.

Comment: Hi, tried your code but navigation bar is not hiding, facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**In your Splash Screen Launcher Activity**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
```

**After Change your Splash Screen Launcher Activity like this**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
         final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 3000;
            /** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
            Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

            int wait = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
            try {
            super.run();
            /**
            * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
            * the wait variable for every 100L.
            */
            while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
            sleep(100);
            wait += 100;

            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } finally {
            /**
            * Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
            * times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
            */
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
            }
            }
            };
            welcomeThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Dedaniya nirenkumar, I have extended ActionBarActivity changed it to activity. With that code i can hide the title bar but not the navigation bar.