# Displaying the captured image in full screen

Tags: android, android-imageview

In my application, I have to show the captured image from camera in full screen like in Snapshot. I could make the camera preview (surface view) to display in full screen. But when I display the captured image in ImageView, it is not displaying in the full screen.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1- If you want your Activity be full screen,do some thing like this:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

(more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052/1043882))

2- If you want your ImageView be full screen,create instance of ImageView then set it as `ContentView` of your Activity or create a layout that image view completely covers that and set that layout as `ContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

I set the scale type property of Image view as 'centerCrop' (`android:scaleType="centerCrop"`). Now its working fine.