# Removing Android Titlebar is not working (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manifest

Good morning. I've been using android studio to try to make an activity/whole app fullscreen.

There are two methods I have tried, one is in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

(and another attempt in the manifest)

```
android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
```

(and another attempt in the manifest)

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

And the other is in code (onCreate)

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Time and time again the bar at the top appears in all my activities as seen in the image below.

Does anyone know how to make that dissapear so its fullscreen please.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28301744/4584675) should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add theme for Activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
```

OR

2) Handle in Activity

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
this.setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

Comment: Applying the theme part to activities in the AndroidManifest.xml file worked. For some reason when trying to have a single Theme file which is referenced from <application> has not worked. Can someone recommend what the best thing to put in each <activity> android:theme part is? It seems being able to remove android:theme in each <activity> and using a single one in <application> would be best right?

Comment: @user3652876 You are right instead of multiple activities you can use theme to application. but now days developer use multiple fragments  and single activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate` of your activities, use

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    .
    .
    .
```