# Intent addFlags fullscreen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fullscreen

Is it possible to switch to fullscreen another app which I launched from my app trougth Intent? I tried this

```
intentScan.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
```

but this code doesn't hide action bar. Thanks for every help!

Comment: You should define whether a layout from an Activity is fullscreen or not in your AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in your AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

(Copied from [Fullscreen Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android))

Comment: I know that I can add it to manifest. But I want to turn into fullscreen mode another app which I launched from my app. Thanks for answer.

Comment: You can't do that, at least without root or adb permissions, you don't have access to its context for that and thus it would be a security issue

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in the next activity's onCreate:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
    boolean isfullScreen =  intent.getBooleanExtra("force_fullscreen", false);

if(getIntent()!=null)
{ 
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: I know that I can add it to manifest. But I want to turn into fullscreen mode another app which I launched from my app. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's why Fragments came about, you have another app entry point with another class and theme, but they all point to the same Fragment and app logic.

Comment: That means that I have to use Fragment?