# Android: Cannot succeed in making activity full screen

Tags: android

I want to do an application that is full screen, that is, I can use all the screen up to the border of the phone and over the triangle, circle, square bar at the bottom (I don't know what this is called, System Bar? System Menu Bar?).

This is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GameScreen gameScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(this.gameScreen);

    }

}
```

My activity code is non existant, just the definition and creation. I tried to do it programatically from answers such as:

[How to set fullscreen in Android R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835053/how-to-set-fullscreen-in-android-r)

or this

[How to make a FullScreen Activity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524972/how-to-make-a-fullscreen-activity-on-android)

But nothing has worked.

I am now trying to use The android XML file.

I created an empty activity and Android studio created a themes.xml file in values.

I modified it to look like this (it originally only had the color definitions):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ColoWords" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

It is my understanding from several questions asked regarding this matter, that this is the proper way to get an AppCompatActivity Full screen. However Nothing, programatic or otherwise works. No matter what I do, I still see the window being cut off before the edge of the phone at the top (where the front facing camara is) and the system menu bar at the bottom

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?