# Can a view cover part of the Android status bar?

Tags: android, statusbar

The navigation drawer is not covering the status bar

[image]

Is there any way to let navigation drawer cover up part of the status bar? Does Android even support this?

Such is doable on iOS, like this.

iOS equivalent functionality depicted below

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWDok.jpg):

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8DGG.jpg):

Comment: You can make your app [full screen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052/3415152). What it does is that it hides the status bar

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I don't wanna make the status bar invisible once and for all. I need to temperately block some of it so that the whole "the navigation menu floats on top" thing makes more sense.

Comment: That is simply impossible because the status bar is not part of your activity's view. It overlays it.