# How to toggle a view from normal screen and full screen and vise versa in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I want to toggle playerview from normal screen to full screen and vise versa
here is my code

mainactivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/video_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.test.player.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </com.test.player.PlayerView>

    <com.test.player.DetailsInfo
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

PlayerView.java

```
public class PlayerView extends LinearLayout{
//Here i am adding surfaceview and
// player control view
}
```

In player control i have a option to toggle fullscreen to normal screen and vise versa.

Can some one help me to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
private boolean toggle = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);


}

public void onFullscreenButtonClick(View view) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (toggle) {
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        toggle = false;
    } else {
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        toggle = true;
    }
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

Let us know if it works.

Comment: I want  playview alone  toggle  between full screen and normal screen, and my playerview is extended from linearlayout