# How can I make a camera app in android with no controls so that only the view from the lense is displayed on the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view, camera

does anyone know how to implement a camera activity so that when the activity is launched, only what the camera lense sees is what is displayed on the screen? I basically want to launch an activity to where it displays a camera view, but with **no** actual buttons on the screen that actually do things like the button to take a picture, button to see the taken pictures, etc. Any help or snippets would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out Google Sample for Camera2 API here [Github repo for Camera2 API](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

And to make and activity full screen check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android) out