# How to create the activity full screen in android programmatically using kotlin.

Tags: android, kotlin

How to create the activity full screen in android programmatically using kotlin.

Thanks!

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/android-overview.html

Comment: You may want to take help from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android if you want to convert it into kotlin then you can use converter or read what @IntelliJAmiya suggested

Comment: Wondering why this question is marked as duplicate and having so many down votes. The question redirected is not showing any code in kotlin lang...

Answer (score 12):

Import Window packages

```
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
```

Add your onCreate method

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)     
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_test)
   }
```

Comment: by using this code my app is crash 

Log:
 Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: add code before set content

Comment: check edited answer