# How to completely hide the status bar on Android in Immersive full screen mode

Tags: android, statusbar, kiosk, android-immersive

I'd like to completely hide the status bar when in Immersive full-screen mode, for the purpose of running a kiosk app. All of the suggested solutions mention methods for preventing the status bar from getting fully expanded, but none show how to completely prevent the status bar from being displayed (then subsequently disappearing) when you drag down on the top of the screen. In Kiosk mode we don't want ANY ancillary activity occurring besides the dedicated app that is running on the device, despite how users may try to interact with the controls or screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need own ROM for your project...

Comment: Yup, I was tasked with this at one point as well. Without access to Android OS code, this isn't doable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Comment: Then how does an app like SureFox do this? They have a kiosk app that allows them to hide the status bar completely, despite any user interaction.