# Webview Video fullscreen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am loading a YouTube video in my app using web-view. But the full screen option is not working.
How can i achieve the full screen.

My Code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Player.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello"/>
        <WebView x:Name="browser" Source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDrTbLXHKu8" HeightRequest="500"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dU6z.jpg)

The youtube fullscreen is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to add the full screen flag ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53337763/11104068

Comment: You need to achieve the full-screen mode by your self, have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/mhaggag/XFAndroidFullScreenWebView/blob/master/XFAndroidFullScreen/XFAndroidFullScreen/Controls/FullScreenEnabledWebView.cs) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom renderer for your `WebView`. [This repo](https://github.com/mhaggag/XFAndroidFullScreenWebView) will help you.
More details about this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101902/webview-and-iframe-video-full-screen-issue) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/310812/#Comment_310812).

Just checked your code with this `WebView` renderer and it's showing fullscreen video after tapping expand control.

Answer (score 0):

simply replace your stack layout with Grid,as following

```
<Grid>
       <WebView x:Name="browser" Source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDrTbLXHKu8" />
</Grid>
```