# HTMLWebViewSource Video FullScreen option is disabled

Tags: html, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to play a video in the WebView on a Xamarin app. The video runs fine as it is expected to do but the fullscreen option on the controls of the video is disabled.

XAML:

```
<WebView Source="{Binding Source}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

Code:

```
public object Source
{
    get
    {
        var HTML = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        HTML.Html = $@"<video controls><source src=""{PathToVideo}""></video>";;
        return HTML;
    }
}
```

[Image of the Webview page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWAbM.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webview Video fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156563/webview-video-fullscreen)

Comment: @Cfun It could, but I just switched to using a MediaElement.

Comment: if problem has been solved could you post your solution as answer , it is helpful to others.