# how make Android apps fullscreeen using javafxports?

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

I have a video streaming application build using JavaFX and successfully ported to Android 7 using Javafxport. Currently, my App is being overlayed by on-screen Android navigation buttons and top status bar. What changes should I make in order to run in full-screen mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Comment: Have you checked the Charm Down Video [service](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/VideoService.html)? It supports fullscreen mode.

Comment: @JoséPereda my application is developed  using openSource JavaFxPorts without Gluon

Comment: Charm Down is open source as well, you don't need Gluon Mobile to use it.

Comment: @JoséPereda  have looked into it but doesn't fit my requirements. I need the whole application to be fullscreen. The app consists of preloader and mainstreamer; mainstreamer has a layout with menu options on either side of the video, which needs user inputs(currently, due to nav bar of android I'm unable to access bottom and the top portion of the app which has also some selectable options). I don't need the video to be fullscreen, just want the mainstreamer app to hide the Android navigation buttons and top status bar so that I can access the whole app.

Comment: You can create a custom service, like in this [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native), and modify the Android implementation according to your needs. Note that some of the changes you want could be probably done directly in the AndroidManifest file.