# Is there a way to play video in full-screen (Landscape) mode in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview, exoplayer

I've gone through many answers here but no luck. below is my code :

```
private PlayerView playerView;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector());
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("videoLink");
    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerDemo"));
    ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);

    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

}
```

and xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I want the video to be opened always in full-screen mode..I'm not providing any button to make it full-screen. ExoPlayer is such a popular library for video streaming so I wonder why it has still not released an easy way for this so common feature. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Create an activity that opens in fullscreen and insert your player there. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052/3410697

Comment: @PedroOliveira tried this solution but still it shows white line on top and bottom ..see https://imgur.com/a/VhAKuls

Comment: Try calling `player.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);`

Comment: @PedroOliveira thanks man, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting as an answer for visibility.

Steps for creating that effect:

- Create a full screen activity as seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052/3410697
- Enable `RESIZE_MODE_FILL` by calling `player.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);` as seen here https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2317