# Android activity is not getyfull screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I got so many answers when i searched about to make an activity full screen i tried many codes but my toolbar became white color (i am not sure the color *there in the screenshot ) as in the screenshot please help me to fix this , through java also i tried by seeing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android) from stack

In style i made

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

And in manifest i made

```
<activity android:name=".colleges"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

[image: Screenshot of what i got after making fullscreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added a toolbar then you have to hide it too.

For hiding statusbar here's code:(boxRoot is your root layout from XML)

```
boxRoot.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: "boxRoot is your root layout from XML" i did not get this point

Comment: i used   Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); but it became white space

Comment: use View.GONE for visibility

Answer (score 0):

put this below code on your on create method before setContentView()

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your style with this:

```
<style name="AppThemeFullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Then change your app theme:

```
<application
   ...
   android:theme="@style/AppThemeFullScreen"
   ...
```

or change single activity theme:

```
<activity
    android:name=".DummyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeFullScreen" />
```

And I think your problem causes because of you are using "android:windowNoTitle".
 Don't use that use this:

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```