# Fullscreen activity android 3.3

Tags: java, android

I need to know how to put an activity in fullscreen, actually I have android 3.3. Thanks.

**This didn`t work = **

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: Check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Where is your main activity layout? It simply needs to have both width and height set to match parent in the parent layout.