# How hide status bar items android

Tags: android, window, statusbar

I went over a lot of answers to stackoverflow
But the best I have use

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
```

It looks like this
[image]

I want to do as in a game
Use this
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#sticky-immersive

But I can not hide status bar items
How hide status bar with items?

This answer does not fit
[Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)
It leaves a black bar instead of the status bar.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Comment: No
The black bar remains in place status bar