# how to open chrome in full screen or kiosk as webview in android

Tags: php, android, webview

I have googled and found out it in chrome it is not possible to go fullscreen without user gesture, however, as per our requirement user gesture is not required.
Alternatively , have found out it can work in kiosk mode.
We can set this kiosk mode in windows as well as in linux, but do not know how to do in android device.
What we are trying to achieve is we have used chrome browser in an android application as a webview and want to open as a part of the android application. It is digital signage where media is controlled from web portal. And a display `php` page to show media, which will run on android. Client has android 6.0
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add manifest to your website. Here you specify how chrome should behave (fullscreen). When website is browsed for first time, use the install option . An icon por the website will be available now. When launched, it will be fullscreen

Check https://web.dev/add-manifest/ on how to add manifest and for the possible values of display

If you want to make the Android activity containing the webview full screen check here [Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

Comment: sorry for delay response. However , we tried nothing happened . We created a `manifest.webmanifest` file and reference on our page as `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` and `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">` by created both `.json` and `.webmanifest` . Our manifest file looks like `{
  "name": "Air Solution",
  "short_name": "Air  Display",
  "theme_color": "#2196f3",
  "background_color": "#2196f3",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/http://18.159.78.142/web/index/39"
}`

Comment: ok. I think there is an issue with start_url, it begins with `/`. But again: first time you open the website via chrome. It should then offer the option to "Add to Desktop" or "Install". Check the 3dots menu for this. An icon for the website will be added. If you launch the website by this icon. chrome will open in fullscreen mode. It's common in some PWA applications

Comment: we are using this URL as a webview in android. So , how can we `Add to desktop` or `install`

Comment: i have tried that URL in chrome of my PC , do not get `Add to desktop` or `install`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I though you were using regular chrome and wanted fullscreen for kiosk mode.   This way (android app) I can't tell you but I have seen it in a project I worked in. The app was just a webview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222195/discussion-between-gabriel-a-lopez-lopez-and-mark).