# Why Action bar always stay as gray color in android?

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

I have video player, everything works, but I do not know how to remove gray navbar, even I declared in manifest

> `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

And idea?

```
   <activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

  </activity>
```

[image]

Comment: This is status bar.

Comment: This isn't the Action Bar. It is called the Status Bar. In order to hide it you need to have a full screen Activity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997241/12811664, follow this to change color. or use @gioravered suggestion to hide it.

Comment: @gioravered, I was try it, but  not help me , it look like black

Comment: @Hafiza, I want to remove status bar, not change color

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `AppCompatActivity` , you need to add new theme

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"/>
```

Comment: I try it before alots, not help

Answer (score 0):

in styles.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Lite.NoActionBar">
     ...
     ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use  this code inside `theme.xml` or `styles.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then inside the `Manifest File` instead of applying the theme inside the activity tag like this.

```
<activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter> 
...
</activity>
```

You ***apply the theme inside the Application Tag instead***

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

              ....
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer but status bar become the black